# Cannot override method of superclass

Tags: java, compiler-errors, overriding

I want my `Widgets` class's `get` method  to extend that of the superclass `org.powerbot.game.api.methods.Widgets`, but I get a compilation error:

[image]

However, the superclass clearly has a matching `get` method: 
[image]

Comment: static methods are not specific to classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` methods are not polymorphic in Java.  In other words, they cannot be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

The @Overide annotation is used to mark an overridden method. Static methods cannot be overridden in java. But you can redefine them. Just remove the annotation. You may optionally call the super class static method inside your sub class static method.